# how change storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType in swift 2.2 (XCode 7.3)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7.3

i have a project and use this code in my project:

```
if storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error:&error ) != nil{
    if error != nil{
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        abort()
    }
}
```

but in swift 2.2 , this codes have error...xcode display this error:

> Extra argument 'error' in call

and another code is:

```
class func saveManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->Bool{

            if managedObjectContext.save(nil){
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
```

in these lines have some error :

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled.

and

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your call to `addPersistentSore...` in a do/try/catch handler:

```
do {
   myNewStore = try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
   // other code on success ....
}
catch let error as NSError {
   Swift.print(error!.localizedDescription)
   abort()
}
```

You can read up on Swifts throw/catch error handling for example here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

Also see Apples documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468860-addpersistentstore (note it is Swift 3.0.1)

Comment: thanks...but you'r answer is wrong..because "try" can not use with "if"

Comment: i have added for you how to take the result. You don't need the if anymore with the try/catch construct.

Comment: it's ok..thanls a lot